# BottomTabNavigator hide item visibility

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I need `OtherStack` to contain `BottomTabNavigator` but it is not visible on it. I only want to access it in `Drawer`, navigation in React Native is so confusing to me.

The closest result I got was this where `OtherStack` is accessed by Drawer and also contains BottomTab, but it's visible and I don't want it.

```
// Stacks
const LogInStack = createStackNavigator({
  Login: {
    screen: LoginScreen,
  },
});

const HomeStack = createStackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen,
  },
  HomeDetail: {
    screen: HomeDetailScreen,
  },
});

const SettingsStack = createStackNavigator({
  Settings: {
    screen: SettingsScreen,
  },
  SettingsDetail: {
    screen: SettingsDetailScreen,
  },
});


const OtherStack = createStackNavigator({
  OtherStack: {
    screen: OtherScreen,
  },
});

// Bottom tab
const MainTabs = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: HomeStack,
    },
    Settings: {
      screen: SettingsStack,
    },
    // Other is here because it should contain bottomTabBar,
    // but Other should not be visible here, only in Drawer can I access it.
    Other: {
      screen: OtherStack,
    },
  },
);

// Drawer
const MainDrawer = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: MainTabs,
    },
  },
  {
    contentComponent: DrawerComponent,
  }
);

// Switch auth
const App = (isSigned = false) =>
  createAppContainer(
    createSwitchNavigator(
      {
        Auth: {
          screen: LogInStack,
        },
        App: {
          screen: MainDrawer,
        },
      },
      {
        initialRouteName: isSigned ? 'App' : 'Auth',
      }
    )
  );

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
const defaultNavigationOptions = {
  tabBarVisible: false,
  header: null
};
```

You can hide bottomBar with this code segment. Example from your code:

```
// Bottom tab
const MainTabs = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: HomeStack,
    },
    Settings: {
      screen: SettingsStack,
    },
    // Other is here because it should contain bottomTabBar,
    // but Other should not be visible here, only in Drawer can I access it.
    Other: {
      screen: OtherStack,
    },
  },
  { defaultNavigationOptions }
);
```

If you want to hide bottom bar for MainTabs, you need to set it like that.

Comment: This is not the result I want. Let it be more specific, when I'm inside OtherStack I should just have Home and Settings in BottomTab, OtherStack itself will not appear or on any other screen. The problem is that today it is visible on all screens and would not see.

Comment: You can set this options just for OtherStack part. Then it will not visible in anywhere

Comment: But if I set this option only to `OtherStack` part it will hide the whole BottomTab when I enter OtherScreen, right? I want the `Other` item to be `hidden at all times` but other items are normally visible.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by setting the drawerLabel to null on the item navigationOptions:

```
// Bottom tab
const MainTabs = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: HomeStack,
    },
    Settings: {
      screen: SettingsStack,
    },
    Other: {
      screen: OtherStack,
      navigationOptions: () => {
          return {
              drawerLabel: () => null,
          }
      }
    },
  },
);
```